# Why isn't my context persisting across navigate between components?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So I have created a profileContext which I am trying to use so that I do not need to fetch the profile data from my API each time i navigate to the userProfile component. The issue I am facing seems to be that my context doesn't seem to be persisting and I cannot figure out why I have put it at the top level in the component tree and I checked it is being set after the initial API fetch is made to get the profileData it is just when we navigate away from the profile page to another page and then come back that the context appears to be empty even though it should consist?

Here are the components involved

top level component
main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthProvider.jsx';
import './config/firebase-config.js';
import { ProfileProvider } from './components/context/ProfileContext.jsx';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ProfileProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </ProfileProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

UserProfile component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useProfile } from './context/ProfileContext';

const UserProfile = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryString = location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const usernameFromParams = urlParams.get('username'); 
  const usernameFromState = location.state && location.state.username;
  const qr_id = location.state?.qr_id;
  const username = usernameFromParams || usernameFromState;
  const viewParam = urlParams.get('view');
  const { profileData, updateProfileData } = useProfile(); // Use the context hook 
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Track loading state
  
  let content;  // will be used to render diff component based on view

   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProfile = async () => {
      // Check if profile data exists in context
      console.log("profile data context ", profileData);
      if (!profileData || profileData === null) {
        console.log("profile data context in if", profileData);
        try {
          let response; 
          if(username) {
            response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/userProfile', {
              params: {
                username: username
              }
            });
          } else if(qr_id) {
            response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getProfile', {
              params: {
                qr_id: qr_id
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.error("Neither User nor qr_id is defined ");
          }
          
          if (response.status === 200) {
            const profile = response.data;
            console.log("profile = ", profile);
            updateProfileData(profile); // Update profile data in the context
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to fetch profile');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching profile:', error);
        } finally {
          setIsLoading(false); // Set loading state to false when done fetching
        }
      } else {
        setIsLoading(false); // If profile data exists, set loading state to false
      }
    };
    fetchProfile();
  }, []);



  return (
    
    <div>
      {console.log("profile data context in the render = ", profileData)}
      {isLoading || !profileData  ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {/* Top section for displaying profile data */}
          <div>
            <h2>{profileData.username}'s Profile</h2>
            <p>Username: {profileData.username}</p>
            <p>Email: {profileData.email}</p>
            <p>Bio: {profileData.bio}</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

ProfileContext:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ProfileContext = createContext();

export const ProfileProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Perform any side effects related to profile data here
        console.log("profile data in context component = ", profileData);
    }, [profileData]);

    const updateProfileData = (data) => {
        console.log("data in update profile data = ", data);
        setProfileData(data);
    }

    return (
        <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ profileData, updateProfileData }}>
            {children}
        </ProfileContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useProfile = () => {
    return useContext(ProfileContext);
};
```

App Router :

```
// AppRouter.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Signup from './SignUp';
import UserProfile from './UserProfile';
import ProfilePage from './temp/Profile';
import Login from './Login';



const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/signUp" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/userProfile" element={<UserProfile/>} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: _"Navigate"_ how?

Comment: @Phil so currently I don't have a nav bar integrated yet so I have just been change the localhost url to my routes, so i tested it by going to userProfile url it fetches the data first time stores in context then changed url to another component and then changed the url back to userProfile url and the context wasn't persistent

Comment: React state is held in-memory only. Once you perform a normal navigation by changing the URL, anything previously stored is lost. You should be navigating using a router

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React data loss on navigation due to re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436540/react-data-loss-on-navigation-due-to-re-rendering)

Comment: @Phil I have an appRouter I have edited the question to include it, is this what you are referring to, what happens then say once I host my app if the user changes the url to a specific route?

Comment: @Phil and the AppRouter component is what App.jsx renders just to clear that up also

Comment: If the user manually changes the path in the address bar then you get a full site load, you will have none of the in memory states you had before the path change.

Comment: @Phil the question you suggested doesn't answer my question as it suggests using Context which I am using i just can't figure why the context isn't persisting when i navigate around my site

Comment: @JacobSmit what is the best way then to work around this and keep the profile data persistent upon the user changing the path in the address bar?

Comment: @taat I think you might have missed the part in the linked post about using `localStorage` for persistence

Comment: @JacobSmit is it better to use a cache to cache the profile data as this will stop the api call having to be made each time but will the cache persist over full site loads?

Comment: The user shouldn't have to navigate around your site by using the address bar, you should provide proper navigation within the app. If the user does need to navigate via the address bar, the app should be made to properly handle the initialisation of the user profile (i.e. send request to server, wait for response) before it actions any redirect / error that it might show otherwise.

Comment: @Phil but that would be poor from a security perspective storing a users profileData in localStorage that would make it accessible to javascript? The profile data has details such as username and email and I plan on adding media in the future which local storage - 5 to 10MB storage limit may not be the best, we wouldn't want to store this in local storage?

Comment: @JacobSmit I know they shouldn't navigate through the url I am just testing every scenario but everyone has done it before, so the approach in the case the url is changed is to just take the hit and make that API call everytime the url is changed but with proper routing the context will persist?

Comment: Yes, if they are manually changing the URL they can wait for the full app to load again. I guess the question I have would be why does it take a problematic amount of time to load a user profile?

Comment: @JacobSmit it doesn't the loading time is good I just want the app to be as efficient as possible and was wondering if there is a way around making the API call that is all, is it not good practise to minimise server side api calls if there is other ways around?

Comment: It depends on the requirements. KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid) is a good idea to follow, especially when starting out. You don't need to over engineering things, if the basic solution will meet the requirements then you can just use that. There is nothing wrong with basic solutions unless a problem has been identified.